# Remove subfolder with URL Rewriting not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to rewrite the URL's contained looks like:
`https://mywebsite/FOF/news/page/page1.php`

I think it's not very aesthetic as url and I would like it to look more like this:

`https://mywebsite/customPage`

This request is very specific for url `https://mywebsite/FOF/news/page/page1.php`

My code works, the urls of the https://mywebsite/FOF directory are rewrite, but on the other hand the main url of my site and the urls of the other files are no longer accessible, I do not understand where my error comes from, if someone can help me

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /    
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^page1$ page1.php    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+FOF/news/page/([^\s]+) [NC]    
RewriteRule ^%1 [R=301,L]   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule (?!^FOF/news/page/)^(.*)$ /FOF/news/page/$1 [L?NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. So you want to hit url `https://mywebsite/FOF/news/page/page1.php` in browser and change it to `https://mywebsite/page1` in browser? Please confirm once.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, yes this is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with your shown samples, could you please try following Rules in your htacces file. Make sure your htaccess file is present aside with FOF folder(not inside it).

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
##Enabling FollowSymlinks and disabling MultiViews options here.
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
##Setting rewrite base to / here.
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
##Rewriting for page1 uri here.
RewriteRule ^page1$ page1.php    
##External redirect rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/FOF/news/page/page1\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /customPage? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^customPage/?$ FOF/news/page/page1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: that work :D, the only thing it's , I want to remove the .php extention ,and that work with https://mywebsite/page1.php but not with https://mywebsite/page1

Comment: @user1887842, so url mywebsite/page1 link should be served by `mywebsite/page1.php`? Please confirm once.

Comment: yes, in the folder https://mywebsite/FOF/news/page/, there is a page1.php and I would like to change the name of page1.php by page1 or a other name like mypage1 or something else

Comment: @user1887842, Sure. Could you please try my updated Rules once and let me know how it goes? Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: With the updated rules that work I give mywebsite/page1, that perfectly remove the .php extention ,:D but with a custom name that not work for the moment

Comment: @user1887842, could you please elaborate on `custom name` which you are mentioning here? Please tell in form of FROM which url TO which url you want to get it.

Comment: I would like this url https://mywebsite/FOF/news/page/page1.php to either become https://mywebsite/page1 or https://mywebsite/clown or https:// mywebsite/spiderman, I know that this weird but I would like to custom the part after https:// mywebsite/

Comment: @user1887842, ok but I have written rules to redirect from `mywebsite/FOF/news/page/page1.php` TO `mywebsite/page1`. So please do let me know what kind of urls are working(including details from where to where they are getting redirected), so that I can understand it better way, thank you.

Comment: What you did is perfect, I just thought if i changed this line RewriteRule ^page1$ page1.php by RewriteRule ^spiderman$ page1.php it would return me mywebsite/spiderman

Comment: @user1887842, oh ok got it. Rules are updated now, could you please do check it once and let me know if these Rules help you? Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: With the updated rules, that not change that keep mywebsite/page1 and not mywebsite/spiderman

Comment: @user1887842, ok is your url is like `http://localhost:80/mywebsite/page1`? To `http://localhost:80/mywebsite/spiderman` you want to redirect? Please confirm once.

Comment: no my url is https://mywebsite/FOF/news/page/page1.php and I would like it to be https:// mywebsite/(spiderman or something else), I don't know if this is really possible to do that ? this is not a redirect but a rewrite with removing subfolder(that work with your rules) and custom name change of php file in my case page1.php.

Comment: @user1887842, can you please confirm once that only and only https://mywebsite/FOF/news/page/page1.php URL should be changed to `http://mysebsite/spiderman` nothing else? If you are looking multiple pages to redirect to Spiderman then it's not possible. Let me know how?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that only this must be changed

Comment: @user1887842, ok kindly do check my edited Rules now and let me know how it goes then?

Comment: it works perfectly: D, you are great. Really thank you for your help and patience. I think my request was a bit odd. Hope this helps other people in my case.
thank you so much

Comment: Yes, thank you once again for your help :)